# How to use Isotope or Masonry with a fixed width?

Tags: fixed-width, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have not been able to find a way to use Isotope (or Masonry) with a fixed width outer container.

It always insists on re-sizing. I've looked through the options, code, google and here and haven't found the answer.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems backwards to the problem 
I was having. Masonry works best with fluid containers but I wanted a fixed width of 980px on my center (main class ie: margin:0 auto; width 980px; )

Then masonry doesn't work... The fix is to find the center or whatever class u use to contain all content to a set width and change it from width to max-width:980px.  This means ur still on fixed width centered container but masonry items will readjust / relayout upon resizing the browser.

I have a module I'm working on at www.digi2020.com - choose menu -> portfolio and u will see that does just this. I've added a lot of bells and whistles but a simple call to masonry will achieve same effect.

Inspect and Check out the .main class and the JavaScript on that page.

Another example using isotope on a fixed width that does not allow items to relayout on resize but still provides filtering can be found on pressedweb.com/portfolio

Comment: Awesome, this answer helped me a lot.  Google Chrome's zoom behavior is different than firefox (and safari, for that matter).  Setting my masonry container to a fixed width caused the layout to break in chrome, but when I changed it to max-width it worked flawlessly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when you set the outer container to `max-width`. I have used `width:960px` and it does not interfere with the masonry grid after resizing the browser window. Maybe check *all* of your outer containers?